# How to permanently remove/disable default Joomla templates

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, update

When I first installed my Joomla 3.x website, I uninstalled the default Joomla templates: Beez3, Protostar, Hathor, Isis.

Every time I upgrade to a new Joomla version, Joomla appears to reinstall these templates back into the `/templates/` & `/administrator/templates/` folder. Furthermore, they don't get recognized and appear back in the administrator panel, they can only be seen from a file manager.

How can I prevent Joomla from reinstalling these directories every time I update my Joomla version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't prevent Joomla from upgrading her core templates. They are in there for a reason as a part of default installation. I am afraid you will just have to learn how to live with them. I did the same, because they used to bug me before, but not anymore...

But if you really want to move them out of your way, you can always Disable them in
`Extensions | Manage | Manage`, dropdown `'Select a type' | Template`, just like any other built-in extension which is not protected.

Comment: Is there a way to have these templates recognized in my Administractor Panel again?

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, it is not complete. Disabling has a similar effect for a user.

Comment: @BodgeIT Let me upvote your comment as a "compensation" for your downvote of my answer. Its all good...

Comment: @Clayton K Yes, you can always re-install default templates, but first you have to recover all missing files by going to Components | Joomla Update then click on "Check for Updates" because only that will show new red button "Reinstall Joomla core files". After performing that reinstallation, you should go to Extensions | Manage | Discover and click "Disover" button, which will find reinstalled default templates and give you an option to re-install them.

Comment: @Mikan suggesting the he suck it up was not an answer that supported.  ->Upvote after edit.

Comment: @BodgeIT Thanx pal... For both, suggestion and upvote... :-)

Answer (score 5):

What I do is to go in:

> **Extensions -> Manage**

and disable any extensions, templates that I don't use. Of course if we are talking about 3rd party extensions, I totally uninstall them - but disable for core extensions does also work, so they are out of my way in most administration tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change sql files of joomla upgrade before you upgrade your joomla. Remove template related insertion.